# C++ Insertion Sort a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to do an insertion sort on a vector of baseball pitchers I created yesterday with help from a previous post.  I want to sort the pitchers in ascending order by ERA1.  I have gotten the insertion sort to work in the past for a set of integers.  I think I have a syntax error in my code for the insertion sort.  Up until trying to add the insertion sort this program was working well.  I get an error - expected unqualified id before [ token.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
#ifndef Pitcher_H
#define Pitcher_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Pitcher
{
private:
    string _name;
    double _ERA1;
    double _ERA2;

public:
    Pitcher();
    Pitcher(string, double, double);
    vector<Pitcher> Pitchers;
    string GetName();
    double GetERA1();
    double GetERA2();
    void InsertionSort(vector<Pitcher>&);
    ~Pitcher();

};

#endif

#include "Pitcher.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

Pitcher::Pitcher()
{
}

Pitcher::~Pitcher()
{
}

string Pitcher::GetName()
{
    return _name;
}

Pitcher::Pitcher(string name, double ERA1, double ERA2)
{
    _name = name;
    _ERA1 = ERA1;
    _ERA2 = ERA2;
}

double Pitcher::GetERA1()
{
    return _ERA1;
}

double Pitcher::GetERA2()
{
    return _ERA2;
}


#include "Pitcher.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

void InsertionSort(vector<Pitcher> Pitchers&);

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    vector<Pitcher> Pitchers;

    cout  << "Pitcher" << setw(19) << "Item ERA1" << setw(13) << 
        "Item ERA2\n" << endl;

    Pitcher h2("Bob Jones", 1.32, 3.49); 
    Pitchers.push_back(h2); 
    Pitcher h3("F Mason", 7.34, 2.07); 
    Pitchers.push_back(h3); 
    Pitcher h1("RA Dice", 0.98, 6.44); 
    Pitchers.push_back(h1); 

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < Pitchers.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << setw(19);
        cout << left << Pitchers[i].GetName() << "$" << 
            setw(10) << Pitchers[i].GetERA1() << 
            right << "$" << Pitchers[i].GetERA2() << "\n";
    }

    cout << endl;

//------------------------------------------------------

    InsertionSort(Pitchers);

//Now print the numbers
    cout<<"The numbers in the vector after the sort are:"<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < Pitchers.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<Pitchers[i].GetERA1()<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl<<endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void InsertionSort(vector<Pitcher> &Pitchers)
{
    int firstOutOfOrder = 0;
    int location = 0;
    int temp;
    int totalComparisons = 0; //debug purposes

    for(firstOutOfOrder = 1; firstOutOfOrder < Pitchers.size() ; firstOutOfOrder++)
    {
        if(Pitcher.GetERA1([firstOutOfOrder]) < Pitcher.GetERA1[firstOutOfOrder - 1])
        {
            temp = Pitcher[firstOutOfOrder];
            location = firstOutOfOrder;
            do
            {
                totalComparisons++;

                Pitcher.GetERA1[location] = Pitcher.GetERA1[location - 1];
                location--;
            }while(location > 0 && Pitcher.GetERA1[location - 1] > temp);
            Pitcher.GetERA1[location] = temp;
        }
    }
    cout<<endl<<endl<<"Comparisons: "<<totalComparisons<<endl<<endl;
}
```

Comment: first indent your code then post

Comment: Try to remove parentheses from `Pitcher.GetERA1([firstOutOfOrder])`.

Comment: Please include the **complete error message**.  It mentions which line of your code has the error.

Comment: `vector<Pitcher> Pitchers&)` to `vector<Pitcher>& Pitchers)` and fix some typos with `pitcher` vs `pitchers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
  for(firstOutOfOrder = 1; firstOutOfOrder < Pitchers.size() ; firstOutOfOrder++)
{
    if(Pitchers[firstOutOfOrder].GetERA1() < Pitchers[firstOutOfOrder-1].GetERA1())
    {    //^^^your way was not right, should first access the object then 
         //access member function
        temp = Pitcher[firstOutOfOrder];
                 //^^^should be Pitchers, similar errors below           
        location = firstOutOfOrder;
        do
        {
            totalComparisons++;

            Pitcher.GetERA1[location] = Pitcher.GetERA1[location - 1];
           //^^^similar error as inside if condition
            location--;
        }while(location > 0 && Pitcher.GetERA1[location - 1] > temp);
                             //^^^similar error as inside if condition
        Pitcher.GetERA1[location] = temp;
        //^^similar error as in if condition and name error
    }
}
```

Meanwhile, you put the `InsertionSort` declaration as a member of the `Pitcher` class

```
  public:
       .
       .
      void InsertionSort(vector<Pitcher>&);
```

and you also declare the same function inside `main`,

```
  void InsertionSort(vector<Pitcher> Pitchers&);
                        //should be vector<Pitcher>& Pitchers
  using namespace std;
  int main()
```

the member function probably should be removed in your case. `InsertionSort` is not a `responsibility` of your `Pitcher` class.

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is homework, you're better off using the build in sort from

```
<algorithm>
```